# Transform Point with Perspective Transform Matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix, transformation, point, perspective

I have the coordinates of a quadrilateral which was photographed out of two different perspectives. Furthermore I have the coordinates of one Point but only from one of the two perspectives. I need to transform the coordinates of this point to the perspective the second photograph of the rectangle was made. Do do this I use OpenCV

I've calculated the Perspective Transform Matrix:

```
cv::getPerspectiveTransform(quad1, quad2);
```

My Problem now is that I don't really know how to transform the Point with the calculated Perspective Transform Matrix. This is probably quite simple but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [the new OpenCV forum](http://answers.opencv.org) for OpenCV-related questions, where I answered a very similar [question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1858/homography-for-cordinates-of-poins/#1859) with a little sample code.

But basically, it's using the

```
void perspectiveTransform(vector<Point2f> origPoints, vector<Point2f> transformedPoints, Mat h)
```

function.

Comment: I think a separate forum for OpenCV isn't as valuable as keeping it on StackOverflow. Especially considering it has been down for over 24 hours now.